# Deleting rows in pandas dataframe based on pair value

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                 'Type':['101','102','101','101','101','102'],
                 'Qty':[10, -10, 10, 30, 5, -5]})
```

I want to remove pair value of df['Type'] = 101 and 102 where df['Qty'] net off each other. The end result would be as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['a','b'],
                     'Type':['101', '101'],
                     'Qty':[10, 30})
```

I tried to convert the negative value into absolute number and remove duplicates as such:

```
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].abs()
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Qty'], keep='first')
```

But then it wrongly give me such dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['a','b', 'b'],
                     'Type':['101', '101', '101'],
                     'Qty':[10, 30, 5})
```

Comment: Do you need remove pairs per users? Also there are only `101` and `102` types? And need test `101` with `102` types ?

Comment: in case you want to remove all duplicates, you can use `keep=False` instead of `'first' `or `'last'`

Comment: @jezrael yes i need to remove pair per user. Actually 102 will always cancel out 101 because 102 is the reversal item for 101. There would only be 101 and 102. I dont get your last question

Comment: @TanzinFarhat i tried that but then i will get df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['b'],
                     'Type':[ '101'],
                     'Qty':[30}) instead of what i exactly want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is create combinations of index values per groups and test if each subgroup contains both `Type`s and sum is `0` for set ot this matched pairs:

```
#solution need unique index values
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

from  itertools import combinations
    
out = set()
def f(x):
    for i in combinations(x.index, 2):
        a = x.loc[list(i)]
        if (set(a['Type']) == set(['101','102'])) and (a['Qty'].sum() == 0):
           out.add(i)

df.groupby('User').apply(f)

print (out)
{(0, 1), (4, 5), (1, 2)}
```

Then remove all pairs if duplicated some value, like here `(1,2)`:

```
s = pd.Series(list(out)).explode()
idx = s.index[s.duplicated()]
final = s.drop(idx)
print (final)
0    0
0    1
1    4
1    5
dtype: object
```

And last remove rows from original:

```
df = df.drop(final)
print (df)
  User Type  Qty
2    a  101   10
3    b  101   30
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are only two `'Type'`s <sup><sup>(in this case `101` and `102`)</sup></sup> then you could write a custom function as follows:

- Build a dictionary with keys containing absolute values of `'Qty'`.
- Values of the dictionary contain a list of `'Type'` values corresponding to `'Qty'`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
def f(x):
    new = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in x[['Type', 'Qty']].itertuples(index=None,name=None):
        if not new[abs(v)]:
            new[abs(v)].append(k)
        elif new[abs(v)][-1] !=k:
            new[abs(v)].pop()
        else:
            new[abs(v)].append(k)
    return pd.Series(new,name='Qty').rename_axis(index='Type')
```

The logic is simple:

- whenever a new key is encountered add it's corresponding `'Type'` to the list.
- if it's already existing key then check if last value i.e. `'Type'` which was added earlier is equal to current `'Type'` value. If they both don't match for example, if `new = {10:['101']}` and current key is `'102'` remove `'101'`. So, `new = {10:[]}`
- if it's key is already existing and last `'Type'` and current `'Type'` match, simply append current `'Type'` to the list for example, if `new = {10:['101']}` and the current `'Type'` is `'101'` then append to it. So, `new = {10:['101', '101']}`.

```py
df.groupby('User').apply(f).explode().dropna().reset_index()

  User  Type  Qty
0    a    10  101
1    b    30  101
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over all records and saving matches in a list that ensures no index is paired more than once seems to work here.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                 'Type':['101','102','101','101','101','102'],
                 'Qty':[10, -10, 10, 30, 5, -5]})



# create a list to collect all indices that we are going to remove
records_to_remove = []
# a dictionary to map which group mirrors the other
pair = {'101': '102', '102':'101'}

# let's go over each row one by one,
for i in df.index:
    current_record = df.iloc[i]
    # if we haven't stored this index already for removal
    if i not in records_to_remove:
        pair_type = pair[current_record['Type']]
        pair_quantity = -1*current_record['Qty']
        # search for all possible matches to this row
        match_records = df[(df['Type']==pair_type) & (df['Qty']==pair_quantity)]
        if match_records.empty:
            # if no matches fond move on to the next row
            continue
        else:
            # if a match is found, take the first of such records
            first_match_index = match_records.index[0]
            if first_match_index not in records_to_remove:
                # store the indices in the list to remove only if they're not already present
                records_to_remove.append(i)
                records_to_remove.append(first_match_index)
                
df = df.drop(records_to_remove)
```

Output:

```
   User Type  Qty
2     a  101   10
3     b  101   30
```

See if this works for you!